# Keras: Mean Squared Error, In which set is the mean taken?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

There are only 2 values involved for each training data row, true value and the predicted value.

The square of the difference between these values is taken.

Where does mean come from?
Does it do this for entire batch and then take the mean?

Answer (score 0):

It does it "element-wise" in the tensors, them it takes the mean of all the axis except the batch dimension.

Finally, if there are sample weights, these weights are multiplied, also element-wise, in the batch dimension.

So:

- elementwise difference: `y_true - y_pred` (all minus all, keeping the same shape)
- elementwise square: `K.square(previous_result)`
- mean in all axes except for batch: `K.mean(previous_result, axis=1)` #or `axis = (1,2)`, or `(1,2,3)` ....

These are visible in the loss function, the weights step is hidden:

- apply sample weights: weights * previous_result
- finally a mean of the remaining dimension